# Python all() method

Tags: python

I'm wondering how the below result yields True.None of the condition is True?

Any inputs?

```
>>> listitem=['a','h','o','t']
>>> valid_compare_diff
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> all(x for x in listitem if x in valid_compare_diff)
True
```

New changes:-

```
>>> listitem=['0']
>>> valid_compare_diff
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> all(x for x in listitem if x in valid_compare_diff)
True
```

How come the results are still True when the list comprehension yield a result..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Henny said, your collection is empty, because you are only looking at those values that *already fill your condition*.

You want to return the results of the check, not the element if the check passed:

```
all(x in valid_compare_diff for x in listitem)
```

With `(x for x in listitem if x in valid_compare_diff)`, you will get all those values of `listitem` that belong to `valid_compare_diff` (in your case, none).

With `(x in valid_compare_diff for x in listitem)`, for each `x`, you take the value of the expression `(x in valid_compare_diff)`, giving you a `bool` for every `x`.

Answer (score 8):

The comprehension will be empty as no value of `x` meets the condition:

`if x in valid_compare_diff`

Hence:

```
>>> [x for x in listitem if x in valid_compare_diff]
[]
```

results in `[]`, which when passed to `all` returns `True`

```
>>> all([])
True
```

This is so because the definition of `all` states that if the iterable passed to it is empty then it returns `True`:

```
all(...)
    all(iterable) -> bool

    Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
    If the iterable is empty, return True.
```

Comment: Clear, concise and correct. I'd just like to add that this makes perfect sense. It's the way "For All" acts in mathematics too. "All the 10 feet tall chickens like to dance", since there _are_ no 10 feet tall chickens, they _all_ love to dance.  It's called Vacuous truth. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks for your insight, I'll read the article tomorrow when I get a chance.

Comment: can you explain my new changes?...all(['0']) and all([]) both yields True..As per the python tutorial, it will yield True only if a iterable is empty..

Comment: @user1050619 not *only* if, just *if*. `all(iterable)` is False if and only if iterable has at least one falsey value.

Answer (score 0):

```
(x for x in listitem if x in valid_compare_diff)
```

says 'gather all the `x`s from `listitem` that are also in `valid_compare_diff`. Passing that through `all()` only cares about those `x`s that you did pick up, and so it will be `True` unless you've picked up atleast one falsey `x` - it doesn't care (or even know) about how you chose those `x`s in the first place.